# What could be a quick and fast way for reordering UI list?

Tags: angularjs, html, typescript, angular

Im using Angular 2 & Typescript .

In my project im presenting a simple list of json objects, the html looks like this:

```
<div>
  <!-- Present List Button -->
  <button md-button
          (click)="showList()"
          class="md-primary"
          title="show list">Cropping</button>
</div>


<md-content>
  <div *ngIf="showList">
  <div class="list-bg"  *ngFor="#list of lists | async">
    ID: {{list.id}} <p></p> Number of Items: {{list.numberOfItems}}
  </div>
  </div>
</md-content>
```

very simple list.

Now I want some kind of method to reorder this list and set the lists array to the new order.

Im looking for a method that a user cal reorder the list however he wants, like change the list by priority.

Could someone please help me to find a method that will be quick to implement and will work good?

(I looked into some drag and drop libraries but I work with specific ver of Angular 2 (2.0.0-beta.15) which non of them support.)

Thanks allot!

Comment: try: lists.reverse();

Answer (score 0):

for this you have to use angular 2 pipe for more information check [this](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/pipes.html)

> **orderBy Pipe**

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
@Pipe({
  name: "orderBy",
  pure: false,
})

export class OrderBy implements PipeTransform {
  transform(array: any, args: any) {
    if (array != null) {
      if (array) {
        let orderByValue = args;
        let byVal = 1
        if (orderByValue.charAt(0) == "!") {
          byVal = -1
          orderByValue = orderByValue.substring(1)
        }


        array.sort((a: any, b: any) => {
          if (a[orderByValue].toString().toLowerCase() < b[orderByValue].toString().toLowerCase()) {
            return -1 * byVal;
          } else if (a[orderByValue].toString().toLowerCase() > b[orderByValue].toString().toLowerCase()) {
            return 1 * byVal;
          } else {
            return 0;
          }
        });
        return array;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

> **Component**

```
import {Filter} from '../pipes/filter';
import {OrderBy} from '../pipes/orderBy';

@Component({
  selector: 'category',
  templateUrl: '../views/category.component.html',
  directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
  providers: [SetupService, HTTP_PROVIDERS],
  pipes: [ OrderBy]
})
```

> **View** for ascending order

```
<md-content>
  <div *ngIf="showList">
  <div class="list-bg"  *ngFor="#list of lists | async | orderBy:'id'">
    ID: {{list.id}} <p></p> Number of Items: {{list.numberOfItems}}
  </div>
  </div>
</md-content>
```

> **View** for descending order

```
<md-content>
  <div *ngIf="showList">
  <div class="list-bg"  *ngFor="#list of lists | async | orderBy:'!id'">
    ID: {{list.id}} <p></p> Number of Items: {{list.numberOfItems}}
  </div>
  </div>
</md-content>
```

Comment: ] Im looking for a method that a user cal reorder the list however he wants, like change the list by priority, can i do this with your suggestion?

Comment: yes you can but in that case you have to pass the object instead of id as a string and from that string it will get the name of object property to sort on or you can do it like this orderBy:true==false ?'id' : 'numberOfItems'